# fabric make error etcd: does not contain package go.etcd.io/etcd/etcdserver/api/snap

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, etcd

I have found that some of us work on the blockchain project - **hyperledger/fabric** has a similar error of the command `**make**` in the local machine with `**go mod**`(`GO111MODULE='on'`):

```sh
build command-line-arguments: cannot load go.etcd.io/etcd/etcdserver/api/snap: module go.etcd.io/etcd@latest found (v3.3.18+incompatible), but does not contain package go.etcd.io/etcd/etcdserver/api/snap
```

And the answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the error up above, but only will work if you had opened the `go mod`, which means the env `GO111MODULE='on'`.

So with the `go mod` on, you will need to run the command in the `hyperledger/fabric` dir:

```golang
go mod init github.com/hyperledger/fabric 
go mod tidy
```

And then if you run `make`, the error will show itself on the terminal.

Now you need to modify the `fabric/go.mod` file with this replacement:

```sh
# replace this :
go.etcd.io/etcd v3.3.18+incompatible
# to :
go.etcd.io/etcd v0.5.0-alpha.5.0.20181228115726-23731bf9ba55
```

and then run

```
go mod tidy
go mod vendor
make clean
make
```

It should be fine now.

Hope this may save you one hour or so.